# Can't access network share using IP address of the server

Tags: windows-xp, networking, smb

I'm facing a strange issue on Windows XP SP3: I can't browse a network share when using the IP address of the server – while I can, using the server's name.

See example below:

```
    C:\SMAC\ARCHE>nslookup dc-mavau
Serveur :  dc-mavau.groupe.sa.colas.com
Address:  10.110.83.10

Nom :    dc-mavau.groupe.sa.colas.com
Address:  10.110.83.10


C:\SMAC\ARCHE>net view \\10.110.83.10
La liste est vide.


C:\SMAC\ARCHE>net view \\dc-mavau
Ressources partagées de \\dc-mavau



Nom du partage  Type    Utilisé comme  Commentaire

--------------------------------------------------------------
BE              Impr.                  BE
CANON           Impr.                  CANON
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: What IP shows up if you ping `dc-mavau`?

Comment: the good one : 10.110.83.10